# The Unanswered, My Tags tab

Tags: discussion, support, questions

The tooltip for the Unanswered tab says:

> questions with tags that I've participated

Surely this should be "questions with tags that I've participated **in**", or maybe "...that I've **actively** participated in".

However, I *think* the tags shown seem to be my favourites, not ones I've necessarily participated in. Certainly for me there's a one-to-one match between the search query and my favourites, some tags of which I've not participated in much if at all.

Should it say something like "Questions with tags that I've favourited"?

Another issue, is that since the only posts that appear are in my favourites (I think) all will be highlighted. IMO there's no point highlighting all posts. Maybe we should highlight posts with multiple matching tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Surely this should be "questions with tags that I've participated **in**", or maybe "...that I've **actively** participated in".

The tooltip gets the point across very clearly. I don't think adding a missing preposition or adjective would greatly enhance it's meaning. It's obvious that the list would try to pop questions with tags one has actively participated in.

> However, I *think* the tags shown seem to be my favourites, not ones I've necessarily participated in. Certainly for me there's a one-to-one match between the search query and my favourites, some tags of which I've not participated in much if at all.

The algorithm must be skewed in favor of tags you have as favorite, and rightly so. There is much better possibility of you knowing the answer for questions with one of the tags as your favorite than the ones with tags that you don't follow but have previously participated in.

Moreover, there are lots of users who don't mark any of the tags as favorite. For them, the "My Tags" tab shows the list of questions with tags they have previously participated in. So, there's no point in changing the description to imply that questions with your favorite tags get displayed. And for similar reasons, questions with your favorite tag get highlighted and other don't.

Comment: I agree it is clear what it means. I still think it would scan better with the "in" added though. I appreciate it's minor, so am happy to accept this as the answer. Thanks for the explanation re. favourites.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Had it been a complete sentence, I would have agreed about including the preposition. But since tooltips are supposed to be short and do the job of getting the point across, I tend to support the missing preposition :-)